# How to add an header to jface Dialog?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to make an header for an dialog(jface) like eclipse has in every window. Like this one: [image: Header]

And how to recreate this header? Is this an canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JFace `TitleAreaDialog`.

You use it much the same as a normal JFace `Dialog` but you can call `setTitle` to set the main title, `setTitleImage` for the image and `setMessage` for the smaller text.